# Why is my .click() not working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, event-handling

I'm writing something fairly basic; however for some reason the jquery `.click()` is not working.  Here is my code:

```
<?php for($r=0; $r<count($result); $r++){?>
    <tr>
        <?php for($c=0; $c<9; $c++){?>
            <td><?php echo $result[$r][$c];?></td>
        <?php }?>
        <td><button name="edit<?php echo $r;?>">edit</button></td>
    </tr>
<?php }?>
```

and

```
$('button[name*="edit"]').click(function(){
    var row= $(this).parent().parent();
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

If anyone can help me with this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you run it inside `$(document).ready`?

Comment: do a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Why not simply put a css class on the buttons? `<button class="editable">`, then `$('.editable')` will get them all. YOu don't need to embed ID values in the buttons - every dom node "knows" where it is in the tree, an dyou can retrieve the actual value from sibling nodes

Comment: which one is the parent().parent(); of the button?

Comment: By not working, I mean nothing happens on `click()`. I tried Marc B's suggestion, it did not work. I tried both in and out of `$(document).ready` as well.

Answer (score 0):

See this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nknw3/)

Note that it alerts the id of the containing row and the text value of the button.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr id='foo'>        
        <td>1</td>        
        <td>
            <button name="editg">edit</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$('button[name*="edit"]').click(function(){        
    var $row= $(this).parent().parent();    
    alert($row.attr('id'));    
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Alerts: -

- "edit"
- "foo"

In your example, did you mean:

```
alert($(this).text());
```

there is no `val()` on `button`.

If this does not answer your question, then perhaps you can change the fiddle to show the problem happening.

**Update**

See this: [jsdfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nknw3/1/)

This uses `$(function()` in case your javascript is in head.